# Drupal redirect / hide page content in form_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In a certain case I do not wish to display a the content of a form when you get to the form_alter stage of my module. I have tried drupal_goto() and unset($form) . In the first case an error is thrown:

```
Warning: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes query: INSERT INTO watchdog...
```

&the second case the form is rendered. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Devel module. Disabling this and it started working.

Comment: Good find. Devel module is usually the first thing to disable if things are acting strangely

Answer (score 0):

This you can also solve by increasing the value of 'max_allowed_packet' to 32M or more in my.cnf or my.ini file.
It is caused by the fact that mysql has to store a packet that is to big.